# Sorting alphabetically in JQuery with two groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I've got a todo list. Each row has a star icon that you can click, exactly like gmail. The difference here is that if you click a star it should sort to the top (higher priority), but also re-sort within the starred group by ascending alpha. Unstarred items sort below, also sorted by ascending alpha. Everything is working as expected except for the alpha sorting. Below is the sort function where I'm doing that. I've verified that everything works below *except* the //sort the arrays by alpha bit...

***Sort fail:***

```
function sortTasks(currList) {
    var starredTasks = [];
    var unstarredTasks = [];
    //create arrays
    $('li.task').each(function(){
        if ($(this).children('img.star').attr('src') == "images/star_checked.gif") {
            starredTasks.push($(this));
        } else {
            unstarredTasks.push($(this));
        }
    });
    //sort the arrays by alpha
    starredTasks.sort( function(a,b){ ($(a).children('p.task-name').text().toUpperCase() > $(b).children('p.task-name').text().toUpperCase()) ? 1 : -1;});
    unstarredTasks.sort( function(a,b){ ($(a).children('p.task-name').text().toUpperCase() > $(b).children('p.task-name').text().toUpperCase()) ? 1 : -1;});
    //draw rows starred first, unstarred second
    $(currList).empty();
    for (i=0; i < starredTasks.length; i++) {
        $(currList).append(starredTasks[i]);
    }
    for (i=0; i < unstarredTasks.length; i++) {
        $(currList).append(unstarredTasks[i]);
    }
}
```

This array has been populated with the task rows in the order they were originally drawn. The data renders fine, but basically stays in the same order.

***Example task row:***

```
<div id="task-container" class="container">
    <form name="enter-task" method="post" action="">
        <input id="new-task" name="new-task" type="text" autofocus>
    </form>
    <h2 id="today">today</h2>
        <ul id="today-list">
            <li id="457" class="task">
               <img class="star" src="images/star_checked.gif">
               <p class="task-name" contenteditable>buy milk</p>
               <p class="task-date"> - Wednesday</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <h2 id="tomorrow">tomorrow</h2>
        <ul id="tomorrow-list">
        </ul>
    <h2 id="future">future</h2>
        <ul id="future-list">
        </ul>
    <h2 id="whenever">whenever</h2>
        <ul id="whenever-list">
        </ul>
</div>
```

Each item in the starredTasks array is an entire task row. I'm assuming that `$(a)` is the same level as `$(li)`?

and here's the function that triggers the sort:

```
$('body').on('click', 'img.star', function(){
    var thisList = '#' + $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').attr('id');
    if ($(this).attr('src') == 'images/star_checked.gif') {
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/star_unchecked.gif');
    } else {
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/star_checked.gif');
    }   
    sortTasks(thisList);        
});
```

Also, I doubt it's worth mentioning, but the data is stored in mySQL and prepopulated via php.

I wasn't sure of a way to use `.sort()` directly on the `$('li')` without splitting it into separate arrays...

Anybody see my goof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you're adding the sorted list back into the DOM. If you're not, then that's the problem. Sorting an array of elements doesn't update the DOM at all.

Furthermore, your sorting is very expensive. It's better to map an array of objects that have the elements paired with the actual values to sort.

Finally, you appear to be using the same ID multiple times on a page. That's just wrong. it may work with jQuery's `.children(selector)` filter, but it's still wrong. You need to change that.

---

Here I map an array of objects that contain a `text` property holding the text to sort and a `task` property that holds the element.

I changed `p#task-name` to `p.task-name`, so you should change that to `class="task-name"` on the elements.

Then I do the sort using `.localeCompare()`, which returns a numeric value.

Finally, the `.forEach()` loop appends the elements to the DOM.

```
var data = starredTasks.map(function(t) {
    return {  task: t, 
              text: $(t).children('p.task-name').text().toUpperCase()
           };
}).sort(function(obj_a, obj_b) {
    obj_a.text.localeCompare(obj_b.text);

}).forEach(function(obj) {
    original_container.append(obj.task);
});
```

This assumes `starredTasks` is an actual Array. If it's a jQuery object, then do `starredTasks.toArray().map(func...`.

The `original_container` represents a jQuery object that is the direct parent of the `task` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm doing an `.append()` just after the sort. I didn't post all the code to make it easier to read. I verified that everything else was working and had narrowed it down to just my sort logic. Multiple IDs of the same name are definitely an issue. I'll change that to a class. Good spot! I'll give your method a try.

Comment: We really need a minimal example that fully reproduces the issue. Otherwise we're just wasting time guessing at your issue. Also, report any console errors you may have.

Comment: updated to show the functions. i was really only having issues with the sort logic though, and didn't want to distract with WIP bits. this is my first post on SO, so I haven't gotten the etiquette down yet. thanks for your help. ;) So, I updated the sortTasks() function to use your logic, and like my original one, it sorts the tasks by star properly, but the alpha is still not working... I wonder what I'm missing. No console errors.

Comment: @5PalmTechnique: what have you debugged? What values have you logged to the console? I see you're calling a function `newSortTasks` but your function is named `sortTasks`. You're traversing up to a `ul` element that's not shown in your code.

Comment: updated html to show ul level. the newSortTasks thing was just a copy/paste error that i forgot to fix in SO. as far as logging to the console, i've verified that the list name is fine and that the object contains the right data, i'll start digging into each stage on the sort to see where it's going wrong...

Comment: @5PalmTechnique: Had to just rewrite your code for sanity (no offense). Works fine with a rewrite. Don't know what the issue was but you were doing a bunch of unnecessary stuff, like creating the separate arrays to do separate sorts. http://jsfiddle.net/c7ju0gLs/2/

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the help. I'm self taught and just started converting my old ASP pages to JQuery a week or so ago. Your more elegant code shows how inefficient my thinking has been. Super helpful!